# javascript to listen two radio buttons response and show a hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, forms

In my html form, I have two set of radio buttons and depends upon its response, I am displaying a hidden `div`

My HTML code:

```
<div class="input-quest">Question 1</div>
<div class="input-resp">
<input onClick="question_1_response_yes();" type="radio" name="button1" value="Yes" checked /><label>Yes</label>    
<input onClick="question_1_response_no();" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" /><label>No</label>
</div>  

<div class="input-quest">Question 2</div>
<div class="input-resp">
<input onClick="question_2_response_yes();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="Yes" checked /><label>Yes</label>   
<input onClick="question_2_response_no();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="No" /><label>No</label>
</div>  

<div id="response-q1-yes-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 3</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q3" name="q3" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="response-q1-yes-q2-no" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 4</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q4" name="q4" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="response-q1-no-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 5</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q5" name="q5" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="response-q1-no-q2-no" style="display:none;">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Question 6</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q6" name="q6" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to display hidden div depends upon a single radio button using onclick function like

```
function question_1_response_yes()  {
$('#response-q1-yes-q2-yes').slideDown("fast");
$('#response-q1-yes-q2-no').slideUp("fast");
$('#response-q2-no-q2-yes').slideUp("fast");
$('#response-q1-no-q2-no').slideUp("fast");
}
```

But I need to display the hidden textboxs depends upon two set of radio buttons selections like

1. question-1 yes and question-2 yes --->  display div `response-q1-yes-q2-yes`
2. question-1 yes and question-2 no  --->  display div `response-q1-yes-q2-no`
3. question-1 no and question-2 yes --->   display div `response-q1-no-q2-yes`
4. question-1 no and question-2 no  --->   display div `response-q1-no-q2-no`

I have to display hidden div ONLY after the two radio buttons selections. How can do this

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/)

Comment: a fiddle with this would be nice and spare us some work :)

Comment: @Sergio:       Here is http://jsfiddle.net/a2fbp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code works for sure.
HTML:

```
<div class="input-quest">Question 1</div>
    <div class="input-resp">
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="Yes" id="1yes" checked /><label>Yes</label>    
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="No" id="1no" /><label>No</label>
    </div>  

    <div class="input-quest">Question 2</div>
    <div class="input-resp">
    <input onClick="response();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="Yes" checked id="2yes" /><label>Yes</label>   
    <input onClick="response();"  type="radio" name="button2" value="No" id="2no" /><label>No</label>
    </div>  

    <div id="response-q1-yes-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-quest">Question 3</div>
            <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q3" name="q3" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="response-q1-yes-q2-no" style="display:none;">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-quest">Question 4</div>
            <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q4" name="q4" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="response-q1-no-q2-yes" style="display:none;">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-quest">Question 5</div>
            <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q5" name="q5" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="response-q1-no-q2-no" style="display:none;">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-quest">Question 6</div>
            <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="q6" name="q6" type="text" value=" " /></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function response(){
  if(document.getElementById("1yes").checked && document.getElementById("2yes").checked){
      document.getElementById("response-q1-yes-q2-yes").style.display="inherit";
  }else if(document.getElementById("1yes").checked && document.getElementById("2no").checked){
     document.getElementById("response-q1-yes-q2-no").style.display="inherit";
  }else if(document.getElementById("1no").checked && document.getElementById("2yes").checked){
     document.getElementById("response-q1-no-q2-yes").style.display="inherit";
  }else if(document.getElementById("1no").checked && document.getElementById("2no").checked){
     document.getElementById("response-q1-no-q2-no").style.display="inherit";
  }
}
```

You may vary the .style.display in the above code to .slideUp or .slideDown too.
It depends on your choice please make this the best answer if it solves your question.
It surely works...